# Jquery ajax equivalent of withcredentials in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, couchdb

I'm currently using angular to send a HTTP GET request to my localhost CouchDB. I've done this through AngularJS:

```
var req =
{
    method: 'POST',
    url: BASEURL+'_session',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: 'name=' + APIKEY + '&password=' + APIPASSWORD,
    withCredentials: true
}
$http(req).then
            (function(result) {console.log(result.data);},
             function(error) {console.log(error)});
```

and was just trying to do the same using AJAX (which I'm a absolute beginner in). 
I can't seem the equivalent version of "withcredentials" in ajax....can anyone help? I get a 401 Unauthorized either way--

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

This is what I have so far:

-edit-

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
     url: BASEURL+'_session',
     headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
     data: 'name=' + APIKEY + '&password=' + APIPASSWORD,
     type: "POST",
     success: function(response)
     {
         alert('Success!' + response);
         var jqxhr2 = $.ajax({
         url: BASEURL+DATABASE+'/users',
         type: "GET",
         success: function(response)
         {
             alert('Success!' + response);

         }
        });
     }
    });
```

Comment: That should work, seems the error could be in your data string.

Comment: $.ajax({
     url: BASEURL+DATABASE+'/'+'users',
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     data: 'name=' + APIKEY + '&password=' + APIPASSWORD,
     type: "POST",xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   },

     success: function()
     {
         alert('Success!' + authHeader);
     }
  });

Comment: are you getting first api's  success callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set `withCredentials` to `true` for cross-domain requests as below:

```
$.ajax({
       url: BASEURL+DATABASE+'/'+'users',
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       data: 'name=' + APIKEY + '&password=' + APIPASSWORD,
       type: "POST",
       xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
       success: function() {
                 alert('Success!' + authHeader); 
                } 
     });
```